# Base64 Encode/Decode in Nativescript With Angular 2

Tags: angular, nativescript

I've looked for an answer everywhere but don't seem to be able to find anything. Using `atob()` and `btoa()` doesn't work. Apparently you cant use them even though intellisense says they are. Plugins from [npm](http://www.npmjs.org) don't want to work either.

All I'm trying to do is decode a base64 string. Am I missing something?

Comment: The downvotes may be due to the brevity of the question, it is hard to say unless people have commented. However, please don't clutter posts with voting/meta commentary - it does not help persuade people to comment if they were not going to anyway.

Comment: Your responses to two answers are also rather brief, to the point of being unhelpful to people who are trying to help. "Doesn't work" is not a useful failure report. As Eddy says, add an example of a failing case into your question.

Comment: Hi, please do not add voting advice into your questions, and please do not add it back in after it has been removed. I've rolled back and downvoted now. If you wish to insist on this edit, please ping me so we can involve a moderator.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because its receiving a lot of bad feedback, its no longer necessary and wont help anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself, using `declare var android;` above the component:

```
let folder = fs.knownFolders.temp();
let start = this.eDoc.cImagePath.lastIndexOf("\\");
let end = this.eDoc.cImagePath.length;
let fileName = this.eDoc.cImagePath.substring(start + 1, end);
let path = fs.path.join(folder.path, fileName)
this.fileNameFull = fs.File.fromPath(path);
let data = android.util.Base64.decode(this.eDocInfo.data, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
this.fileNameFull.writeSync(data);
```

That decodes the base64 and leaves it readable to show as a pdf. Android Only

Answer (score 4):

Native methods

Android

```
const text = new java.lang.String("Yolo 10000");
const data = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
const base64 = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(data, android.util.Base64);
```

IOS

```
const text = NSString.stringWithString("Yolo 10000");
const data = text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
const base64 = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(0);
```

Coutesy of  [@trinix](https://discourse.nativescript.org/u/triniwiz)  on this page https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/how-to-base64-encode-a-string-in-nativescript/345

---

**UPDATE**

Here is what I have, and it's working for me

```
const text = new java.lang.String("Yolo 10000");
const data = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
const base64Encoded = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(data, android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP);
console.log(base64Encoded);

const base64Decoded = new java.lang.String(android.util.Base64.decode(base64Encoded, android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP), "UTF-8");
console.log(base64Decoded);
```

OUTPUT (Nativescript Android)

```
JS: Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode. 
JS: WW9sbyAxMDAwMA== 
JS: Yolo 10000
```

Comment: first, thats encoding but im trying to decode, second, that method doesn't work, ive tried

Comment: `export function decode(args) {
    var text = args;
  var data = android.util.Base64.decode(text, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
   var decoded = new java.lang.String(
     data,
     java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8
   );

   return decoded;
}`  This works for me in decoding the base64string